# How to solve Resource linking failed error?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I updated Android Studio, Flutter, and gradle.
And always have the following error...

Do you have any solution for this?

```
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
     error: resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka (appID):style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
```

My build.gradle:

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()    def localPropertiesFile =
    rootProject.file('local.properties')    if
    (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
          localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)        }    }

       def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
       if (flutterRoot == null) {
           throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk 
       in the local.properties file.")
       }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')

    flutterVersionCode = '24'


    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.25'


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
    android {
        configurations {
            all*.exclude module: 'core' // This removes all other versions of `support-v4` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
        }
        compileSdkVersion 33
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "AppID"
            minSdkVersion 33
            targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        namespace 'com.mechengjp.math'
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2"
    
    }
```

```
flutter doctor -v:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale en-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/sae/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (3 days ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sae/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```